# How to run coroutine and get results from already running `asyncio` `loop` from sync function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

There's a running asyncio loop (for example,`scrapy` spider). I'm intercepting results from one of the callbacks through the sync function (middleware, can't be async). I can't create a new loop because there's one running, but I need to run some coroutines in `async` mode (`aiohttp` requests).

So, the current solution is to create a nested loop through `nest_asyncio`, then run `loop.run_until_complete`, and get results. It works, but doesn't feel production-ready because the solution is quite hacky.

I can't run `loop.run_until_complete` without a nested loop, because the main loop would keep running, while I need immediate results.

So, the question is - how could I run some coroutine and get its results from the sync function, while having a continuously running main loop?

**P.S.** Because I'm working within running spider (running loop), creating a new loop would cause `RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running`, and running `loop.run_until_complete` will cause `RuntimeError: This event loop is already running`.

Comment: `I can't create a new loop because there's one running` I don't really understand that part. What exactly prevents you from running a separate loop in a separate thread for example? And communicate between them via `run_coroutine_threadsafe` or something?

Comment: @freakish because I'm working within running spider, creating a new loop would cause `RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running`, and running `loop.run_until_complete` will cause `RuntimeError: This event loop is already running`. Does it make sense? :)

Comment: @freakish I could be missing some parts, so feel free to ping me if I need to update the question :)

Comment: Perhaps I haven't been clear. At startup (not inside callback) start a new thread, with a new loop with `.run_forever()`. Then call `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe` from the callback with the new loop as parameter.

Comment: @freakish oh, yup, it makes sense, I'll test. Could you add it as an answer?

Comment: Test it first, please, cause I'm not 100% sure it works. And I can't test it myself at the moment.

Comment: @freakish Got it. It would take some time then; I'll with results.

Comment: @freakish Currently, I can't control the process outside the callback, so can't check it either, task limitations. If you could check it and post it as an answer - I would be glad to mark it as a correct one :)